# When the user changes the button onClick again executes

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I have not yet signed in and I click the button : it gives alert to login first
And after that as soon as I login with google (via firebase auth) then the script again executes and this time it executes as logged in function and pushes me to another page...

```
<Button
key={q}
id={q}
onClick={handleClick}
>
  some Text
</Button>
```

And here is handleClick function:-

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let name = e.target.offsetParent.id;
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) { 
    if (user) {
      history.push("/testPage/" + btoa(name));
    }else{
      window.alert("Login To Continue");
    }
  });
};
```

Before signing in when I click the button the else statement executes... but as soon as I sign in then without clicking any button the if statement executes.

How do I remove the second execution i.e. once I click the button it gives me response and after I login, it should not again give me a response untill I again click it.

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behavior of your code. Do you have question?

Comment: I want to avoid the second execution of code

Comment: Do you understand the line `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged`? You are subscribing to an observable. Every time the observable fires your observer is called. Why do you use this design pattern if you don't want to use it? You can store the subscription returned by the function to unsubscribe. Or you could just not subscribe to an observable.

Comment: Oh yes, I just have to remove the subscription... I just did... It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subscribing to an observable. Every time the observable fires your observer is called. You can store the subscription returned by the function to unsubscribe. Or you could just not subscribe to an observable and use the property:

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let name = e.target.offsetParent.id;
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
  if (user) {
    history.push("/testPage/" + btoa(name));
  }else{
    window.alert("Login To Continue");
  }
};
```